# Entity Framework Code First configuration with multiple one-to-many relationships pointing to a single table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am building an application with many different objects (tables), many of which have a need to have a one-to-many relationship to an "Attribute" object. For example, I could have five different objects - A, B, C, D, E - and each of these needs to have an Attributes property - A.Attributes, B.Attributes, etc.

My question is, how would be the best way to structure this in EF Code First? This Attribute class may end up having 15-20 different classes that have a relationship with it.

Currently, a configuration for one of the "parent" classes looks like this:

```
        HasMany(rdp => rdp.Attributes)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

However, this will create a foreign key column on the Attribute table (e.g., "A_Id", "B_Id", etc). So if I have 20 different classes with attributes, the Attribute table will have 20 different foreign keys.

Is there any better way to structure this?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to make Attributes a [ComplexType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx)?

Comment: @JeremyCook: A complex type, from what I know, is only good for one-to-one relationships. Each parent class (A, B, C, etc) can have zero, one, or many attributes, so I don't think a complex type would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce an AttributeList type that maps to its own table. I.e. you could model the list as an entity.

A, B, C, D, E would have a one-to-one association to the AttributeList, with the foreign key to the AttributeList on the A, B, C, D and E classes.

Each AttributeList object contains many attributes, or in other words there is a one-to-many relationship from AttributeList to Attribute.

Now you have a single type with one-to-many to the Attributes and you only need a single foreign key to the AttributeList on the attributes.

Comment: But wouldn't this just move the many-foreign-keys issue to a different table (AttributeList instead of Attribute)? I'm not sure if this really solves the issue?

Comment: The difference is that the relationship between e.g. A and the AttributeList is one-to-one which in turn means you han have the foreign key in A. Likewise for B, C, D etc

Comment: Ah, I see. That is actually a nice solution. It introduces a new class to the mix, but I like that the database structure is much more organized. I'll mark this as the answer.